# apex - remove item from dynamic list

Tags: apex, list, custom-controller

The regular Salesforce community sent me here to ask these questions. 
I'm pretty new to apex and controllers so I'm not sure if I Googled it correctly so please be gentle if this is a super obvious solution.

I have a list that fetches data from an object in Salesforce. I'm using HEDA so everything is school related.
The parent object is a Course and the comes the Course Offering. As part of the Course Offering, we offer something called 'Study Hall'.

we created a VF page where students can sign up for both 'Course' and 'Study Hall'. 
For the 'Course' part we created a drop-down that lists all courses, including Study Hall.
For the 'Study Hall' part we created a multi-select that only lists the study halls.

**My Question is how do I remove every 'course' called 'study hall' from the 'Courses' drop-down?**

This is the code for the 'Courses' drop-down:

```
    public List<SelectOption> getCourses(){
    String year = String.valueOf(Date.today().year());//.substring(2);
    year = 'School Year '+year+'%';

    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    List<hed__Course_Offering__c> courseOffering = [SELECT Id, hed__Course__r.Name FROM hed__Course_Offering__c WHERE hed__Term__r.name LIKE :year ORDER BY hed__Course__r.Name ASC NULLS LAST];
    for(hed__Course_Offering__c co : courseOffering){
        options.add(new SelectOption(co.hed__Course__r.Name, co.hed__Course__r.Name));
    }

    return options;
}
```

and here is how we were able to do the reverse of what I want for Study Hall:

```
    public List<SelectOption> getStudyHalls(){
    String year = String.valueOf(Date.today().year());//.substring(2);
    year = 'School Year '+year+'%';

    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    List<hed__Course_Offering__c> courseOffering = [SELECT Id, hed__Course__r.Name, Name FROM hed__Course_Offering__c WHERE hed__Term__r.name LIKE :year AND hed__Course__r.Name = 'Study Hall'];
    for(hed__Course_Offering__c co : courseOffering){
        options.add(new SelectOption(co.Name, co.hed__Course__r.Name + ' - ' + co.Name));
    }

    return options;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE and thank you for including relevant information and code in your question.

It looks like you can modify your query in `getCourses()` to include `WHERE ... AND hed__Course__r.Name != 'Study Hall' ...`, inverting your second snippet. Is that not what you're aiming at?

Comment: @DavidReed
Thank you so much for your warm welcome and thanks for the solution. I know it was something simple. I've been thinking way to complicated instead of just using `!=`
for those in the future who are encountering the same: adding `AND hed__Course__r.Name != 'Study Hall' `did the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Comment to Answer for posterity).

Modifying the query in `getCourses()` to include the course name in the `WHERE` clause achieves this objective without any additional Apex:

`WHERE ... AND hed__Course__r.Name != 'Study Hall' ...`

Comment: (got it - thanks David) @DavidReed Thank you so much for your warm welcome and thanks for the solution. I know it was something simple. I've been thinking way to complicated instead of just using != for those in the future who are encountering the same: adding AND hed__Course__r.Name != 'Study Hall' did the job.